# How can I check with the recognizer, if I have a subview clicked?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

When I click on a image I want to show another popover, but it doesn't work!

My handle Tap method looks like :

```
-(void)handleTapView:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
   CGPoint startPoint = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
   NSLog(@"handle Tap VIEW!!!!!!!!");

   if ([recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] ) {
      NSLog(@"Tap Image!!!!!!!!");        
   }
   else if ([self.popover isPopoverVisible]) {
      [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];        
   }
   else {
      ShapesListViewController *shapes = (ShapesListViewController*) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShapesListViewController"];

      UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:shapes];
      UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];

      shapes.delegate = self;

      self.popover = pop;   

      CGRect popoverRect;
      popoverRect.origin = startPoint;
      popoverRect.size.width = 1;
      popoverRect.size.height =1;

      [pop presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
   }   
}
```

In viewdidload :

```
ImageView *imgv = [[ImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imagNamed:@"delete.png"]];
imgv.center = CGPointMake(250,250);     
[self.view addSubview:imgv];

ImageView *imgv2 = [[ImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear.png"]];

imgv2.center = CGPointMake(400,400);
[self.view addSubview:imgv2];


//Tap Recognizer
self.singelTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapView:)];
[self.singelTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.singelTapGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a separate gestureRecogniser to each view whose gestures you want to capture - in your case, both of your imageViews.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR1, *tapGR2;
SEL selector = @selector(handleTapView:);
tapGR1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                 action:selector];
tapGR2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                 action:selector];
       [imgv1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGR1];
       [imgv2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGR2];
```

Don't attach a tapGR to their superview.

Then you also need to set `userInteractionEnabled` on each of the imageViews otherwise they will ignore touches (UIImageView defaults to `userInteractionEnabled = NO`):

```
        imgv1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        imgv2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

In you `handleTapView` you need to reorganise slightly. Change the `else if` in you conditional sequence to `if` otherwise the third clause will never get triggered.

The `recognizer.view` for each of the recongnizers will correctly identify the imageView that was tapped. That will be the rect that the popover should present from in the coordinates of the imageView's superview - it's `frame` property.

So:

```
 [pop presentPopoverFromRect:recognizer.view.frame 
                      inView:self.view    
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                    animated:YES];
```